# R package manual leaves a lot of blank space

Tags: r, package, manual

I'm finishing up writing the man pages for my R package. One of the man pages, called "*pkgname*-package.RD" leaves a lot of blank space between the start of the details and where the text actually shows up. I have no clue why though. Did anyone run into this problem? Here's my code for that part:

```
\details{

\tabular{ll}{
Package: \tab iPAC\cr
Type: \tab Package\cr
Version: \tab 0.3\cr
Date: \tab 2012-06-06\cr
License: \tab GPL-2 \cr
}

To identify amino acid clusters ........
}
```

It goes to an entire new page before it prints the table, leaving about 85% of the current page blank. Thanks!

Comment: I can't answer your question, but I would recommend using [roxygen2](https://github.com/yihui/roxygen2) for more efficient and less buggy documentation.